# Hiding a custom Joomla Admin User Group

Tags: user-groups

We have a commercial application used by different companies. We created custom user groups and access levels (not using Author, Editor, etc).

We have a group called SiteAdmin. This customer group has access to the Administrator console and can Enable/Disable end users and assign them to groups.

We have a group called ABCAdmin. This group is for developers and people who work at our company. I have them in the Groups hierarch 'under'  - a child of - SiteAdmin. This group has more rights than SiteAdmin and can access components that SiteAdmin cannot.

The trouble is, SiteAdmin can see and assign this group to their users. Can I stop this? Can I hide this group?

Answer (score 1):

When you're editing a user then the contents of the Assigned User Groups tab is generated by the code in administrator/components/com_users/tmpl/user/edit_groups.php. As with all `tmpl` files you can create an override within the administrator System / Administrator Templates / Atum Details and Files.

The code in edit_groups.php is just

```
echo HTMLHelper::_('access.usergroups', 'jform[groups]', $this->groups, true);
```

which runs the function `usergroups()` within libraries/src/HTML/Helpers/Access.php.

So you can just move that function into edit_groups.php directly, remembering to include the appropriate `use` statements, and setting manually the parameters to that function.

The code gets a list of the usergroups on the system and cycles through them to output the checkboxes for each. I've just included code to skip over where the usergroup title is ABCAdmin. Obviously you'd need to do a bit more work to decide based on the current user whether the usergroup should be skipped or not.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Access\Access as AccessCheck;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\UserGroupsHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper;

$name = 'jform[groups]';
$selected = $this->groups;
$checkSuperAdmin = true;

static $count;

$count++;

$isSuperAdmin = Factory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin');

$groups = array_values(UserGroupsHelper::getInstance()->getAll());

$html = [];

for ($i = 0, $n = count($groups); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $item = &$groups[$i];

    if ($item->title === "ABCAdmin") {
        continue;
    }

    // If checkSuperAdmin is true, only add item if the user is superadmin or the group is not super admin
    if ((!$checkSuperAdmin) || $isSuperAdmin || (!AccessCheck::checkGroup($item->id, 'core.admin'))) {
        // Setup  the variable attributes.
        $eid = $count . 'group_' . $item->id;

        // Don't call in_array unless something is selected
        $checked = '';

        if ($selected) {
            $checked = in_array($item->id, $selected) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
        }

        $rel = ($item->parent_id > 0) ? ' rel="' . $count . 'group_' . $item->parent_id . '"' : '';

        // Build the HTML for the item.
        $html[] = ' <div class="control-group">';
        $html[] = '     <div class="controls">';
        $html[] = '         <label class="form-check-label checkbox" for="' . $eid . '">';
        $html[] = '         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '[]" value="' . $item->id . '" id="' . $eid . '"';
        $html[] = '                 ' . $checked . $rel . '>';
        $html[] = '         ' . LayoutHelper::render('joomla.html.treeprefix', ['level' => $item->level + 1]) . $item->title;
        $html[] = '         </label>';
        $html[] = '     </div>';
        $html[] = ' </div>';
    }
}

echo implode("\n", $html);
```

Comment: If `selected` is an empty array, then the `in_array()` call will not be terribly taxing, right?  If you still want to check, you could consolidate as `$checked = $selected && in_array($item->id, $selected) ? ' checked="checked' : '';` Also as a topical reference: [What's the proper value for a checked attribute of an HTML checkbox?] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/7851868/2943403)  I might personally use `sprintf()` with numbered placeholders to build the html markup to avoid concatenation and variable declarations/access.

Comment: Why a `for()` loop instead of a `foreach()`?  Is it necessary to make each object ($item) explicitly moifiable? Is this not the natural behaviour of objects anyhow?